# Como impedir a rolagem de um determinado elemento?

Tags: css, rolamento

Tenho uma lista com vários itens, sendo o primeiro elemento uma `<div>`. Eu quero que essa `<div>` fique sempre na mesma posição (visível na parte de cima), independentemente da barra de rolagem se mexer para cima ou para baixo. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```css
li {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
    </div>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
    <li>Item7</li>
</ul>
```

Nesse código acima, eu quero que o primeiro item da lista (no caso a `<div>`) não se mova quando o usuário mover a barra de rolagem para baixo. Como posso fazer isso em CSS?

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas talvez usar `position: sticky` e `top: 0` na `div` seja o caminho para o que você quer

Comment: Por que eu recebi downvote? Como posso melhorar a minha pergunta?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 não dá pra eu falar por outras pessoas, mas talvez [edit] pra colocar o que tentou e onde teve dificuldade talvez ajudasse. Primeiro que tem N jeitos de fazer, depende dos requisitos. E outra coisa é que ficou um "faz pra mim" mesmo que não tenha sido proposital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vale lembrar que DIV não deve ir dentro de UL, e realmente acho que você nem precisa fazer essa estrutura dessa forma, veja https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-ul-element:

> Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

Mas nem cabe na pergunta algo tão opinativo

Para resolver a questão de fixar na tela use **position: fixed**

```css
ul > div {
    position: fixed;
}

ul {
    padding-top: 1px;
}

ul > li:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 32px;
}

li {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
    </div>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
    <li>Item7</li>
</ul>
```

Ou position:sticky

```css
ul > div {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; /*necessário para o sticky*/
}

li {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
    </div>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
    <li>Item7</li>
</ul>
```